# Splitting BZip2 is not working

Tags: hadoop, compression, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, bzip2

I have 1.2GB file in Hadoop, compressed in BZip2 codec. Our Hadoop YARN cluster has **10 nodes**. HDFS **block size is 128 MB** so I think the file is **splitted into 10 blocks**. BZip2 should be splittable codec so I thought when I start processing the input file, Hadoop executes 10 map task (one for each block). But when I look at job logs, I can see only one Map task.

I did not find any settings which limits number of mappers in YARN (in contrast with Hadoop 1).

What am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've never used BZip2, but I think this issue may have to do with your `fileInputFormat`  You may also need to configure your fileInputFormat plz take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24452267/317027).